# Getting the ACROSS variable value in Proc Report

Tags: sas

(Cross posted on [SAS Communities site](https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/Getting-the-ACROSS-variable-value-in-Proc-Report/m-p/252085#U252085))

I am interested in using the value of an ACROSS variable in the URL of my Call Define statement in COMPUTE statement.

In the example below, can PROC REPORT give me access the value of each TYPES variable value...as the columns are being built, so that I can include the value in the URL link? Can I access the value from a COMPUTE statement using the N variable?

```
options missing="";
data REPORT;
 input VARIABLE $ TYPES $;
 datalines;
VAR1 TYPE1
VAR1 TYPE2
VAR1 TYPE3
VAR1 TYPE5
;
PROC FORMAT ;
 VALUE $TYPE
 'TYPE1'='Type 1'
 'TYPE2'='Type 2'
 'TYPE3'='Type 3'
 'TYPE4'='Type 4'
 'TYPE5'='Type 5';
Run ;
proc report data=REPORT nowd;
 column ("Variables" variable) ("TYPES" types,n);
 define variable / '';
 define types / across '' format=$type. preloadfmt;
 define n / '' format=comma12.;
 compute types;
  If _c2_>0 then
   call define("_c2_","style","style={url = '<MY URL>' );
 endcomp;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a single *value*'s value, the way you constructed that:

```
proc report data=REPORT nowd;
 column ("Variables" variable) ("TYPES" types,n);
 define variable / '';
 define types / across '' format=$type. preloadfmt;
 define n / '' format=comma12.;
 compute types;
  If _c2_>0 then
   call define("_c2_","style",cats("style={url = '",_C2_,"'" ));
 endcomp;
run;
```

You can't access row-level values of course, since across variables don't work that way.

Alternately, if you're trying to get the "Type 2" etc. into the name, I think you would go this route (using a format, and *COL* instead of "*C2*").  I don't think there's a way to directly access the across value itself.

Since you're presumably constructing these compute blocks individually through use of a macro, I probably would eschew the format and just pass the value of the variable to the macro directly if you can.  If not, then the format may be useful.

```
PROC FORMAT ;
 VALUE $TYPE
 'TYPE1'='Type 1'
 'TYPE2'='Type 2'
 'TYPE3'='Type 3'
 'TYPE4'='Type 4'
 'TYPE5'='Type 5';
 value NType
 1='Type 1'
 2='Type 2'
 3='Type 3'
 4='Type 4'
 5='Type 5';
Run ;
proc report data=REPORT nowd;
 column ("Variables" variable) ("TYPES" types,n);
 define variable / '';
 define types / across '' format=$type. preloadfmt;
 define n / '' format=comma12.;
 compute types;
  If _c2_>0 then
   call define(_COL_,"style",cats("style={url = '",put(_COL_,NType.),"'" ));
 endcomp;
run;
```

Comment: I believe you are right. The answer to my question is I cannot get at the across variable's value...but I think your code leads me to a solution. Thanks.